# Salesforce MVP Nominations -2019

Tags: discussion, mvp

### **Public service announcement:**

The [MVP nominations](https://nominations.salesforcemvps.com/s/) are open from now until December 9th, 2019.

Feel free to nominate those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be users or moderators or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

Read this Blog:- [Nominate Your Trailblazer Community Mentors and Champions to Be a Salesforce MVP](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/11/nominate-trailblazer-mentors-salesforce-mvp.html)

Comment: Guess i (as marketing cloud user) am going for Zuzanna or Ivan Razine this year since most people to vote for already have an mvp status or work for salesforce and are therefore excluded in the vote (like lukas lunow). Otherwise it would kind of always be Gortonington - this guy is insane ;) Thanks to all that are contributing to SFSE!

Comment: Remember to submit feedback for _existing_ Salesforce MVPs too. We have a great group of them contributing here on SFSE who deserve recognition for their community impact.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick +1 on Zuzanna. I see her rocketing upwards in the ranks, with numerous posts each day, all with great scores. If she continues like this, Adam Spriggs will soon have his #1 spot challenged :-)